# Zooming in a PictureBox with SizeMode set to Stretch in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, zooming, crop, picturebox

So I have a pictureManager program I am creating for class.  The pictureBox used for viewing the images has to have SizeMode set to stretch as to the professor's specs.  I can't figure out how to use my hsb and vsb values to zoom the image.  He calls it "cropping" but really its just a zoom on the image, but I can't seem to get this to work when I click my apply button.  I've tried various solutions I found online, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Could someone could show me how to take the pictureBox.Image and zoom it and then return it to pictureBox.Image?  Thanks!

Comment: we cant tell you what is wrong with what you tried if you dont share what youve tried

Comment: i've tried various things such as using rectangles for cropping and then returning it to the pictureBox and using graphics to draw a cropped image back to the pictureBox.  Neither of which would work.  I have scrapped all the code that didn't work so I can't post it here.  If someone has an idea as how to get started or knows a solution it would be useful.

Comment: Place the picturebox in a panel and adjust the size and position of the picturebox. Done and you can even scroll around easily.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment said: Place the picturebox inside of a panel. I furthermore added a trackbar control with Minimum = 1 and Maximum = 10 on the form and enable AutoScroll on the Panel.
To zoom you just need this code if you set the Picturebox.Sizemode to StretchImage

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub AdjustSize()
    Dim zoommult As Double = TrackBar1.Value
    PictureBox1.Width = CInt(PictureBox1.Image.Width * zoommult)
    PictureBox1.Height = CInt(PictureBox1.Image.Height * zoommult)
End Sub
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    AdjustSize()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AdjustSize()
End Sub
End Class
```